# How do news websites constantly update stories?

Tags: php, html

Basically, how is it possible that news websites (such as CNN and Fox News) are able to pump out multiple articles a day and have them on the front page of their website? I doubt that each person who writes an article individually uploads a page to the website. Do they simply type into a text box and a pre-built computer "algorithm" takes care of the rest? How is it able to replace old news with new news on the front page? Is there a particular coding language used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways or concepts/frameworks to achieve this. It totally depends upon your requirement. There can be a constant call by your client to the server to check if any new posts have arrived and if yes, it can be displayed without page refresh. By the term "without page refresh", there are several languages or frameworks that can do this. There can be a publish/subscribe system that can send posts to your client application's back-end immediately after it receives a new post. When it comes to PHP, you cannot do this. You require some asynchronous support like AJAX, or any framework like Angular or React.